# Ошибка с пакетом при загрузке в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Так получилось, что удалили моё приложение из Google Play, соответственно пришлось сменить имя пакета, чтобы загрузить повторно. Но при попытке загрузки apk в Google Play выдает ошибку: `Название пакета "старое название пакета" уже используется в другом приложении.` Что делать? Кто сталкивался?

Comment: Посмотрите по всему проекту где осталось старое название пакета. Это может быть в манифесте или gradle файлах.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, я просто рефакторинг не везде сделал. @ЮрийСПб

Comment: а почему удалили Ваше приложение ?

Comment: Из-за названия. @researcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите по всему проекту где осталось старое название пакета. Это может быть в манифесте или gradle файлах.